# Batch rename files in subfolders to parent folder name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I am writing a batch script to rename CSV files in sub folders to be the same name as their parent folder. For example the file `R:\Royal Mail\Results\202008101416151232.rm\results.csv` would become `R:\Royal Mail\Results\202008101416151232.rm\202008101416151232.rm.csv`. There is only ever one CSV in each folder.

After thats done the file is moved up a directory so that another piece of software can process it. I've got this working, but the problem is that it currently renames the files in the main folder as well as the sub directories. For example it would rename `R:\Royal Mail\Results\202008101416151232.rm.csv` to `R:\Royal Mail\Results\Results.csv`.

This is the code I have so far:

```
@echo off

set folder="\\rackstation\Couriers\Royal Mail\Results"

rem Rename CSV files to parent folder name
for /r %folder% %%D in (.) do (
  for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /A:-D "%%D"') do ren "%%D\%%F" "%%~nxD%%~xF"
  echo %%D
)

rem Move CSV files to previous folder
FOR /R %folder% %%i IN (*.csv) DO MOVE "%%i" %folder%

rem Deletes empty folders
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir %folder% /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%i"
```

I've tried a couple of things but haven't managed to add an if condition to say if that `%%D = "\\rackstation\Couriers\Royal Mail\Results"` then don't rename the file.

Can anyone modify this script to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PowerShell script will accomplish this and present a warning if there are multiple .csv files in one directory. When you are satisfied that the files will be moved and renamed correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Move-Item` command.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'C:\src\t\Royal Mail\Results' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $FileToMove = Get-ChildItem -File -Path $_.FullName -Filter '*.csv'
        if ($FileToMove.Count -eq 1) {
            $NewBaseName = Split-Path -Path $_.FullName -Leaf
            Move-Item -Path $FileToMove.FullName `
                -Destination (Join-Path -Path $_.Parent -ChildPath "$NewBaseName.csv") -WhatIf
        } else {
            Write-Warning "Directory $($_.FullName) contins multiple .csv files."
        }
    }
```

If you are not able to use the PowerShell console, save the script above in a file, Move-RoyalMailFiles.ps1 an run it in cmd.exe or a .bat file script using:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File 'Move-RoyalMailFiles.ps1"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following method should only perform the task for any subdirectory which contains only one CSV file, so you shouldn't need to worry if, for some reason, you have a subdirectory containing two of them. It uses `Dir` to process the directory names in order that the directory parsing has finished before processing the files. This ensures that a renamed and moved file is not recycled back into the loop. If there is only one CSV file, then you don't need to know its name and can just use the glob, `*.csv`, for the move and rename action and if that action is successful, try to remove the directory, *(which will only succeed if it is now empty)*.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "folder=\\rackstation\Couriers\Royal Mail\Results"

For /F Delims^=? %%D In (
    'Dir /B/S/A:D-S-L "%folder%"'
)Do (
    Set "_="
    For /F "Skip=6Tokens=3" %%C In (
        '""%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" "%%D" Null "*.csv" /L /NFL /NDL /NJH"'
    )Do If "%%C"=="1" If Not Defined _ (
        Set "_=T"
        Move /Y "%%D\*.csv" "%%D\..\%%~nxD.csv"&&RD "%%D" 2>NUL
    )
)
Pause

GoTo :EOF
```

You could also use `PushD` to ensure that you're within the sourcefolder from the outset, returning only after you've finished.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "folder=\\rackstation\Couriers\Royal Mail\Results"

PushD "%folder%" 2>NUL||GoTo :EOF
For /F Delims^=? %%D In (
    'Dir /B/S/A:D-S-L'
)Do (
    Set "_="
    For /F "Skip=6Tokens=3" %%C In (
        '""%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" "%%D" Null "*.csv" /L /NFL /NDL /NJH"'
    )Do If "%%C"=="1" If Not Defined _ (
        Set "_=T"
        Move /Y "%%D\*.csv" "%%D\..\%%~nxD.csv"&&RD "%%D" 2>NUL
    )
)
PopD
Pause

GoTo :EOF
```

*Please note, that I have not taken account of the fact that any subsequent runs of the script, could feasibly move and rename the same file up another level. In order to deal with such things I'd need to know more information about your specific tree structure and naming patterns before considering which may be best.*